# Exporting to Excel with PHPExcel and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am trying to export some data to an Excel sheet using PHPExcel. However, it leaves me with a blank page and nothing else (I understand that this is normal, however the download does not trigger either).

EDIT : Opening a new question for the rest of this problem. Thanks for the help on this all!

Am I doing something wrong here? This is my code (updated as per above)

Problem : SOLVED. Error : Mismatch in variable name ($RowCount vs $Rowcount).

```
<?php
$download="";
if (isset($_GET['surveyid'])) {
//Survey ID
$download = $_GET['surveyid'];
require_once('../Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$query=sprintf("SELECT b.question_id as qid, a.question as ques, b.response as response, count(b.response) as count
FROM v3_sai.survey_responses b 
INNER JOIN v3_sai.survey_questions a ON a.id = b.question_id AND a.survey_id=%d
group by b.response, a.question
order by b.question_id;",GetSQLValueString($download,"int"));
$resultdl= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowcount=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl)){
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $row['qid']);
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowcount, $row['ques']); 
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowcount, $row['response']);
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowcount, $row['count']); 
$rowCount++; 
} 
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

}
```

Comment: have you looked in your php error log to check for errors? is your warning level in the php.ini set to E_ALL? post any errors from these two sources..

Comment: Warning level is set to E_ALL! Where can I find the php error log?

Comment: If you mean the php_error file in wamp's "Logs" folder, it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did some mistake in your SQL query:

```
"SELECT b.question_id as qid, a.question as ques, b.response as response,  count(b.response) as count ..."
```

See on `count(b.response) as count`. Change alias `count` to another.

Also remove `;` in end of query.

**EDIT**

Function `GetSQLValueString` is not defined and not native.
Change code to:

```
$query = "SELECT b.question_id as qid,
                a.question as ques,
                b.response as response,
                count(b.response) as cnt
          FROM v3_sai.survey_responses b 
          INNER JOIN v3_sai.survey_questions a 
             ON a.id = b.question_id 
                AND a.survey_id=".intval($download)."
          group by b.response, a.question
          order by b.question_id";
```

Also change this line:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['cnt']);
```

Comment: Made these changes, still nothing :(

Comment: you sure that `$_GET['surveyid']` is not empty? While I don`t see more mistakes.

Comment: The query works when I execute this in MySQL Directly. But doesn't work here. Doesn't work even if I replace the query with a simple "Select * from table"

Comment: Still blank.. But isn't phpExcel supposed to lead to a blank page or something? :O

Comment: do `var_dump($query);` and `var_dump($objPHPExcel);`

Comment: Neither of the var_dumps are working if I have this line in my code -
`require_once('../Classes/PHPExcel.php');`

If I take that off, the var dump for query shows -
`string 'SELECT b.question_id as qid,

                a.question as ques,

                b.response as response,

                count(b.response) as cnt

          FROM v3_sai.survey_responses b 

          INNER JOIN i3_sai.survey_questions a 

             ON a.id = b.question_id 

                AND a.survey_id=1

          group by b.response, a.question

          order by b.question_id' (length=391)`

Comment: its means,that bad path to `PHPExcel.php`. Check path - `'../Classes/PHPExcel.php`.

Comment: Nice catch! Okay that solved the blank problem, now my var_dump for query shows properly, but var_dump of $objPHPExcel is still showing blank... I there some way I can share my code fully with you? Teamviewer/Email or something?

Comment: vladimir.zabelo@gmail.com . I shall look.

Comment: Ok I got the excel download to work. The error was that I was calling "RowCount" while I'd initialized it as "Rowcount". Now the problem is that the excel that I download just contains the elements of the download page, not the data from the table

Comment: also: always, after generating file and output , you need insert die or exit. In you case `$objWriter->save('php://output'); die;`

Answer (score 1):

Blank pages usually mean display_errors is off...  Which makes debugging a pain.

Set, or add the following to your php.ini, and restart the server (p.s. if you have multiple php.ini files, use the phpinfo() function to make sure you are editing the right one).

```
display_errors = On
```

I also turn on error logging so I can find errors and fix them after the fact, so these php.ini file edits will enable it:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = n:/uniservers/coral/php_errors.log (set your destination here).
```

Once you have display errors turned on, it should be a piece of cake for you to find the error.

Joey